# Adding click event to JQ slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

This is the webiste I run : http://bit.ly/1a3lbaf

The image slider was made in jq javascript by the guy who originally created the website and I'd like some help to add working links on the `<li><a>` triggering the animation of the script.

Here is the code I have :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jq(document).ready(function(){
    if ( jq('#slider-home ul#slider').length == 1 && jq('#slider-home ul#slider li').length > 1  ){
        var homeslidenav = new Array([!YAMS? &get=`tv` &from=`nav-slider`!]);
        jq.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink = function(pager, currSlide, clsName) {
            jq(pager).each(function() {
                jq(this).children().removeClass(clsName).eq(currSlide).addClass(clsName);
            });
                        jq('#navwh').stop(true, true).css('width', currSlide * 138).animate({ width: '+=138' }, 4800 );
        };
        jq('#slider-home ul#slider').cycle({
            fx                : 'fade',
            pause             : true,
            pager             : '#nav-menu',
            pagerEvent        : 'mouseover',
            timeout           : 4000,
            activePagerClass  : 'active',
            onPagerEvent      : function(a){
                jq('#navwh').css('width', a * 138).animate({ width: '+=138' }, 4800 );
            },
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
                var chtml = '<li id="hotel' + (idx + 1) + '"';
                if (idx == 0) chtml += ' class="first"';
                chtml   += '><a href="#">' + homeslidenav[idx] + '</a></li>';
                return chtml;
            }
        });
    }
});
//]]>
</script>
```

I've been able to change the `pageEvent` from `click` to `mouseover` as I find it more practical. Now I'd like to preserve the animation but in the same time add working links instead of the useless `<a href="#">` in the `<li>`. I've tried putting an actual url in the `<a href="#">` but it doesn't work as I suppose the onPagerEvent overrides the `<a>` (I'm not fluent in js as you might have noticed).

Could someone please help me find a way to add this working links ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

onPagerEvent is not doing anything to your links - it is just adjusting the width of the white bar that goes along the bottom of the images (that indicates how long until the next image shows)

The site is using the jQuery cycle plugin - you can find the documentation here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

The updateActivePagerLink function is what is responsible for updating the links (by the way, I visited the site and the links appear to be working - are you trying to add more links?)  The links themselves are coming from the list items inside the `<ul id="slider">`, like this:

```
<li style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 7; opacity: 0; width: 966px; height: 390px;"><a href="/en/hotel-pont-royal"><img src="/assets/images/groupe/sliders/SliderHome-3_en.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
```

To add a new image with a link, just add a new `<li>` with the format above (and with the correct href in the `<a>`) - you don't need to modify any JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I want to do is not add new images to the sliders but to have the same link on the image abivr and to the matching tab below (on the name of the hotel) so that if you hover the name it shows the image and if you click it takes you to the hotel homepage.